# Can Apache ant target detect whether property was overridden on command line?

Tags: ant

I'd like to change the logic in one of my ant targets dependent on the source of the property.  The initialization of our ant targets import a file of properties, but when we want to override a property we specify it on the command line.  Is it possible for the ant targets to know whether the property came from the initial property file versus the command line?

If the properties file has property "my.property" and then the command line shows:

```
ant -buildfile buildthis.xml my.target.to.call  -Dmy.property=overridesfilevalue
```

would the "my.target.to.call" be able to detect and define logic based on whether the "my.property" was passed in from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant has a condition named `isset` that will check whether or not a property is set. You can simply run this condition prior to loading your properties file and then base your build logic on the result.

Example:

```
<condition property="property.override.detected">
    <isset property="property.to.override" />
</condition>

<property file="build.properties" />

<target name="do-this-if-the-property-was-overridden" if="property.override.detected">
    ...
</target>

<target name="do-this-if-the-property-was-not-overridden" unless="property.override.detected">
    ...
</target>

<target
    name="default"
    depends="
        do-this-if-the-property-was-overridden,
        do-this-if-the-property-was-not-overridden"
/>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I'll give it a try tomorrow.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Worked as you suggested.  Thanks again.